# Placing an image over text inside a div?

Tags: html, css

Inside a `<div>` I have text that's centered. I would like to place an image on it so that it is aligned to the right side of the text and placed on top of the last character.

Any structure or code (e.g. CSS or a second `<div>`) or actual CSS/HTML would help.

```
img {
 position: relative;
 width; 100px;
 height: 100px;
 float: right;
}
```

but the image just sits near the text.

Comment: Parent div: `position: relative` / Label and image: `position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0` / Label: `z-index: 1`

Comment: Absolute allows the elements to lay over one another. They are positioned **relative** to the div, so the div must be set to relative

Comment: Thank you. I had to change a few things - but it worked. Here's what I've done: 
`img {
  position: absolute; 
  right: 5px; 
  top: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
}`